# How does distilled water or water filtered by reverse osmosis affect the taste of coffee?

Tags: flavor

I've heard some people say not to use distilled water in pour over coffee because the lack of minerals will negatively affect the taste. Is there any evidence for this? How specifically does it affect the flavor and does the same apply to water filtered by reverse osmosis?

Comment: related: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3/does-the-hardness-of-water-matter-when-making-coffee?rq=1

Comment: I would personally like to see this question edited and clearly ask what the difference is solely between distilled water and water treated by reverse osmosis. Otherwise, you basically have a very similar question as the one EdChum linked.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard that the mineral content in water assists in the distribution of the particulate that's extracted when brewing coffee. While I've not used distilled water, I have used reverse osmosis water (I live in an area with very hard water). I tend to prefer using the reverse osmosis water to the tap water. I don't particularly care for the taste of distilled water on its own, which is why I have avoided using it in coffee.