# Book recommendation: a guide about coffee to a beginner?

Tags: espresso, coffee-culture, recommendation

I really want to learn more about coffee, but I think the web is too large and therefore confusing. So I have decided to start with a good book. Which books (preferably below 20 USD) can you recommend? Just a good and informative beginner guide to espresso and coffee in general?

Comment: Hi @JohanL, could you please take a look at https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/which-books-do-you-recommend-to-read-for-people-who-are-interested-in-coffee ? A slightly different but in essence the same question. You can always search keywords in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Hoffman's "**The World Atlas of Coffee**." 
 He gives you history, tells you about different methods of brewing, roasting, and teaches about growing and processing as well.  A very well rounded introduction.

[The World Atlas of Coffee](http://www.theworldatlasofcoffee.com/)

So far as a book focussed more on brewing, I recommend Rao's "**The Professional Barista's Handbook**."  His blog (also linked below) is also a tremendous source.

[The Professional Barista's Handbook](https://www.scottrao.com/the-professional-baristas-handbook-1/)